# Is bitcoin client really downloads the full transaction info?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I started learning bitcoin and found this wiki: https://learnmeabitcoin.com/beginners/network

And there is this statement:

*When you run the client it will connect to other nodes and start downloading a full copy of the blockchain (the file that contains all the verified transactions). After that, your client will start receiving transactions from other nodes and relaying them around the network.*

Is it really true that each bitcoin client downloads the full transaction history?
Unsure if that scales...

And if someone could provide a good official doc about explaining how bitcoin works?